# Python: Count uniq line(s) between 2 files

Tags: python, text-files, counter

```
 First File | Second File

    bob        | greg
    bob        | larry
    mark       | mark
    larry      | bruce
    tom        | tom
```

With the code bellow I get output:
**bob**, but I need to get **bob x 2**

```
with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as file1:
     with open('some_file_2.txt', 'r') as file2:
         diff = set(file1).difference(file2)

 with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
     for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

Comment: shouldn't you also get `larry`? Or is that a typo in the second file?

Comment: If the second file has `bob` once, how many times should you see `bob`?

Comment: You get `bob` once because sets do not contain duplicates. e.g. `len(set(file1))` is 4

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the difference of two `collections.Counter` objects.

```
import collections

with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    c1, c2 = collections.Counter(f1), collections.Counter(f2)
    result = c1 - c2
    # Counter({"bob": 2})

with open("output.txt", "w") as outf:
    for line, count in result.items():
        outf.write("{} x {}".format(line, count))
```

Comment: You can iterate on the `elements()` of the `results` object rather than needing an extra loop for the count.

Comment: Very nice, but I do not need repeating lines, I need just count number near of every uniq line. Need not bob, bob but bob : 2 or bob x 2.

Comment: .format(line, count)) not correct displaying. but with (count, line) is ok but shows 2 x bob, how to change bob x 2 (easier to analyse data with that displaying.) Show pls, how to sort from biggest to smalest count number. Thx a lot. Feel the power of python, beginning to learn )